# Select first 10 rows of a column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you please let me know how to select first 10 rows for every cusip in the below table

```
SELECT [dt_dim_id],
       [cusip_num],
       sr.[product_dim_id],
       [acct_dim_id],
       [product_name]
FROM [csr_prod].[dbo].[stock_rec] AS sr,
     [csr_prod].[dbo].[product_dim] AS pd
WHERE sr.product_dim_id = pd.product_dim_id
  AND dt_dim_id = 20180927
ORDER BY dt_dim_id,
         product_dim_id,
         acct_dim_id;
```

Comment: Slight detour...but you really need to start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been available for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Some whitespace and line breaks go a long way too to making your SQL readable. Also, using the alias of the table on your column references. Someone who doesn't know your system has no idea if `[dt_dim_id]` is in table `[stock_rec]` or `[product_dim]`.

Comment: What's a cusip?

Comment: Cusip referrs to cusip_num in the query

Comment: oh... I see that the question already has an accepted answer now, but could'nt he just have used `select top 10 [columnName].....` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` with a partition over your groups and order by whatever you need, then filter for the first 10 rows:

```
;WITH paging AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cusip_num 
                                  ORDER BY dt_dim_id, product_dim_id, acct_dim_id) n,
           [dt_dim_id],
           [cusip_num],
           sr.[product_dim_id],
           [acct_dim_id],
           [product_name]
      FROM [csr_prod].[dbo].[stock_rec] AS sr,
           [csr_prod].[dbo].[product_dim] AS pd
     WHERE sr.product_dim_id = pd.product_dim_id
       AND dt_dim_id = 20180927
)
SELECT * FROM paging WHERE n <= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply`:

```
select . . .
from [csr_prod].[dbo].[stock_rec] sr cross apply
     (select top (10) pd.*
      from [csr_prod].[dbo].[product_dim] pd =
      where sr.product_dim_id = pd.product_dim_id and dt_dim_id = 20180927 
      order by ?  -- whatever column defines the first 10 records
     ) p
```

Comment: `order by product_dim_id` will be non deterministic as all rows will have the same value